# Отрезать путь к файлу

Tags: java

Всем привет,перейдем сразу к делу.
У нас есть строка:

```
String text = new String("C:\\home\\work.txt");
```

На выходе мне нужно сделать work
Как отрезать txt,я знаю:

```
text = text.substring(0 , text.indexOf(".txt")); 
System.out.println(text);
```

На выходе получим **C:\home\work**
А как получить просто work,кстати название файла будет меняться,и директория тоже,может это вообще надо делать с помощью регулярок 
Начало :

```
 String text = new String("C:\\home\\work.txt");
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("C:\\s*");//Его нужно закончить!!))
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
 System.out.println(matcher);
```

Короче помогайте)

Comment: Детский сад какой-то...

Comment: Бывает,что сказать,лучше бы написали ,как проблему решить

Comment: @ваняя, а в доку лень заглянуть?

    lastIndexOf(int ch)
          Returns the index within this string of the last occurrence of the specified character.

    substring(int beginIndex)
          Returns a new string that is a substring of this string.

Т.е. что-то вроде

    String filename = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf('\\')+1);

только try/catch видимо добавить надо.

Comment: Я уж разобрался,спасибо try не надо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Велосипедисты, блин.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
String path = "C:\\home\\work.txt";
String fileName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(path);
```

Comment: FilenameUtils,к сожалению нет его

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Не вообще эта библиотека не установлена ,подскажете как установить ,и откуда скачать ,только спасибо скажу.Хотя хотелось бы обычными средствами без всяких библиотек

Comment: Если нет какой-то библиотеки - жми на красный крест слева на полях и он тебе сам предложит то, что стоит импортировать в проект

Comment: import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
ее нужно из инета качать

Comment: в чем проблема?
Скачай, добавь..
Вот небольшое описалово: http://hashcode.ru/questions/101595/java-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-jar-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B2-eclipse

Comment: Воо,то,что нужно,ну ,а обычными средствами не справится?
2)ну вот я ваш код киданул,а дальше,что,его fileName,это work.txt,будет сразу

Comment: >> а обычными средствами не справится?

Это и есть обычные средства, предоставляемые фреймворком.

Comment: Ну, так распарси еще раз, какие проблемы то?

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю просто распарсить text и достать оттуда нужный тебе work.

Парсится как-то так:

```
String text = new String("C:\\home\\work.txt");   
String[] pars = text.split("\\");   
String work = pars[2]; // Что-то типа такого
```

И уже из этого массива можешь достать свой work

Comment: а как это сделать просто на вывод?можно вообще поподробнее

Comment: Не ну ,а как от нее избавится,не работает

Comment: от кого избавиться? Что не работает?
У тебя одна проблема - не знаешь как из урла достать кусок пути - тут либо делай, как Flammable сказал, либо погугли, как парсить строчку с помощью split

Comment: Мне кажется с регуляркой ,легче было бы

Answer (score -2):

```
String text = new String("C:\\home\\work.txt");   
String[] pars = text.split("\\\\");   
System.out.println(pars[pars.length-1]);//тут получили work.txt
String[] work = pars[pars.length-1].split("\\.");
System.out.println(work[0]);//а тут получили просто work
```

Это максимально подробно :)

Код не отобразился полностью, нужно добавить ещё слеши и тогда всё заработает, теперь должен работать!